# The correct usage of a foreign key with a dependent table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a rails app in which a model named `ClassEvents` belongs to the `Users` model. I'd like to flag `Users` with `is_approved` and use some logic in my view to decide whether a `ClassEvent` should be shown.

Ideally, I don't have to look into the `Users` table each time I need to figure out if the `ClassEvent`'s parent `User` has the `is_approved` flag set.

My plan is to create the `is_approved` row in the `User` table and a separate `is_approved` row in the `ClassEvent` table. This feels redundant and an opportunity for nasty bugs.

Is this a case for a foreign key in `ClassEvent`?

What's the correct *Rails way* for this situation?

Comment: Generally, I wouldn't denormalize like this unless you have to for performance reasons.  You're right - you're introducing the opportunity for data integrity problems.  Have you considered using .joins() or .includes() to avoid the n+1 query problem?

Comment: An include would work here. Granted, the number of queries would be large but not massive, so I can see the point about this being premature optimization... But it does seem like it would be a simple change to the schema that would mean not worrying about it.

Answer (score 0):

If `ClassEvents` already belongs to the `Users` model, then you already have a foreign key association, something like this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

In that case you can get only the events from approved users like this:
`ClassEvent.joins(:user).where('users.is_approved' => true)` unless you're dealing w/ huge amounts of data, the performance would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eager loading to load all joined data upfront.

Assuming this kind of association:

```
belongs_to :parent_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

You can load the ClassEvent in the controller like so:

```
@class_event = ClassEvent.includes(:parent_user).find(params[:id])
```

Then you can check it in the ClassEvent view like so and it will not do a separate query to the User record:

```
<% if @class_event.parent_user.is_approved == true %>
    <!--output class event data here-->
```

See the "Eager Loaded Associations" section on this page for more details:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Note too that foreign keys are not automatically set up by Rails at the database layer.  I've used this nice gem to handle that in the past: https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner